# Using Sublime Text 2 for LaTeX

Tags: compiling, editors, viewers

Is anybody using Sublime Text 2? I use it quite frequently for coding, it by far my favourite editor. But I never used it for LaTeX. There is a package called LaTeXTools for editing and viewing LaTeX files, but I can't get it to compile and view on Linux. The author seems to be focusing on Windows and OS X.

Has anybody used Sublime Text 2 for LaTeX? Does anybody know how to make it work for Linux?

Comment: I've used the package, but only on OS X, sorry.

Comment: This is very vague, and unlikely to have a clear answer => Not A Real Question.

Comment: This question could be merged with this active one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60222/latex-with-sublime-text-2

Comment: Now the LaTeX plugin for Sublime 2 supports Linux, scroll down to the bottom: https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools